# Angular drag-and-drop directive adds characters to file extension

Tags: javascript, angular, angularjs-directive

There is a usual drag-and-drop directive in Angular. Everything works well, but it doesn't always work.
Sometimes in evt.dataTransfer.files[0]?.name comes either undefined or a changed file extension, for example, if the image1.jpeg file is dragged, then in the event the name is image1.jpeg0:-9:478:21

It is not clear what it is and where 0:-9:478:21 is added from. The last digits are always the same 478:21, only the first digits change. And this is only in Chrome. I haven't noticed this behavior in Firefox yet.

Working example here https://stackblitz.com/edit/file-upload-drag-n-drop-hye6lv?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

```
  @HostListener('drop', ['$event']) public onDrop(evt){
    evt.preventDefault();
    evt.stopPropagation();

    console.log(evt.dataTransfer.files[0]?.name); // undefined or  
                                                  // image1.jpeg0:-9:478:21
    let files = evt.dataTransfer.files;
    let valid_files : Array<File> = files;
    this.filesChangeEmiter.emit(valid_files);
  }
}
```